# How can I best create an employee AND certifications record in my tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm designing software that could potentially be used by several people at once.
My program will have the ability to "create an Employee," which entails filling out a form that is then used in a SQL query to insert a record into `Employee` and `EmployeeCertifications`.

Right now, `Employee.id` is a primary key and identity column. I have two stored procedures, `Employee_CreateEmployee` (which inserts a record into `Employee`) and `Employee_CreateCertifications` (which inserts a record into `EmployeeCertifications` with a **provided** `emp_id`).

I'm in the process of integrating these stored procedures into the employee creation process in my software, but am faced with a potential issue of more than one user trying to create an employee at a given moment. I was originally thinking of having my program execute `Employee_CreateEmployee`, then running a query to get the highest `id` (most recently created employee), and using the result for procedure `Employee_CreateCertifications`.

Is there a better way to go about this? I have thought about potentially using a transaction for all of these queries and executions but do not know if this will also leave room for error.

Comment: @DaleK if you wouldn't mind demonstrating how I could return the ID, I would love to accept that as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [scope_identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to obtain the latest ID inserted and use an [output parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on your first stored procedure to return the new ID for use by the second:

```
create procedure dbo.Test1
(
    @Input1 nvarchar(128)
    -- ...
    , @NewId int out
)
as
begin
    set nocount, xact_abort on;

    insert into dbo.MyTable (Column1 /* 2, 3... */)
      select @Input1; -- @Input2, @Input3 ...

    set @NewId = scope_identity();

    return 0;
end;
```

Then call as:

```
exec dbo.Test1 @Input1, @NewId out;

exec dbo.Test2 @NewId, @OtherInput1;
```

Comment: @sirius_pain And feel free to use a transaction too..